# Parallelism and Synchronization

Tags: c#, java, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Imagine you are utilizing Parallelism in a multi-core system.

Is it not completely possible that the same instructions may be executed simultaneously?

Take the following code:

```
int i = 0;

if( blockingCondition )
{
  lock( objLock )
  {
    i++;
  }
}
```

In my head, it seems that it is very possible on a system with multiple cores and parallelism that the blockingCondition could be checked at precisely the same moment, leading to the lock being attempted at the same moment, and so on...Is this true?

If so, how can you ensure synchronization across processors?

Also, does the .net TPL handle this type of synchronization?  What about other languages?

**EDIT**
Please note that this is **not** about threads, but Tasks and Parallel-Processisng.

**EDIT 2**
OK, thanks for the information everyone.  So is it true that the OS will ensure that writing to memory is serialized, ensuring multi-core synchronization via volatile reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lock like you have described here is a "[Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29)" style lock on the objLock. As you've noted, it is entirely possible, under a multi-core system, for the two "lock" calls to *begin* simultaneously. However, any high level application environment which uses monitors will have translated the monitor into [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) requests (or, depending on your OS and language particulars, mutex requests) in the compiled byte code.

Semaphores are implemented at the operating system and/or hardware level, and higher level languages bind to them. At the OS level, they are "guaranteed" to be atomic. That is, any program acquiring a semaphore is guaranteed to be the only one doing so at that point in time. If two programs, or two threads within a program attempt to acquire the lock at the same time, one will go first (and succeed), and the other will go second (and fail).

At this point, the "how do you ensure synchronisation" stops being a problem for the application programmer to worry about, and starts being a problem for the operating system designer and the hardware designer.

The upshot of it is, as an application coder, you can safely assume that "lock(objLock)" will be an atomic call no matter how many CPUs you plug into your system.

Comment: So, are you saying that the OS will ensure synchronization of tasks among multiple cores, in a true-parallel environment?

Comment: @ Miguel - Yes. The OS is responsible for making sure that attempts to acquire locks will never happen simultaneously, even in a true-parallel environment.

Answer (score 2):

To understand why this works, bear in mind:

1. Locking a lock (i.e. incrementing a
   lock semaphore on the object) is an
   operation that blocks if the object
   is already locked.
2. The two steps of `lock`, a) checking the lock
   semaphore is free, b) and actually
   locking the object, are performed
   **'simultaneously'** - i.e. they are a
   monolithic or *atomic* operation as
   far as relationship between CPU and
   memory is concerned.

Therefore, you can see that, if 2 threads enter your `if`-block, one of the two threads will acquire the lock, and the other will block until the first one has finished the `if`.

Comment: @miguel, can you describe the difference between threading and parallelism?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806499/threading-vs-parallelism-how-do-they-differ

Comment: i guess my point was that my question is regarding Tasks on parallel cores, not threads on a single core

Comment: @miguel: Your OS+Framework+Library aim to make the single/multi core distinction as invisible as possible.

Comment: This answer is correct with a single core, multiple core, or multiple CPU on most architectures (ccNUMA). The "atomic" natures of the locking is actually done across all the cores.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is precisely why we need a special mechanism like `lock` and cannot simply use a boolean flag.

The solution to your 'simultaneous' problem is in the algorithm that `lock` (which calls `Monitor.Enter()`) uses. It involves memory barriers and knowledge of the very lowlevel memory mechanics to ensure  that no 2 threads can acquire the lock at the same time.

Note: I'm talking about .NET only, not Java.

Comment: Henk: Is this the case that Erica is speaking of?  i.e. the OS will ensure synchronization of memory/tasks across cores?

Comment: @miguel: Funtional, Yes. `Monitor` uses the lighter weight `Interlocked` class, and does not need help form the OS (= expensive) but can guarantee correctness on multiple cores.

Comment: @Henk: but in a true-parallel environment, surely Interlocked only assures atomicity on the CPU upon which the instruction is executing?

Comment: I guess the read/write to the memory location itself might be serialized by the OS?

Comment: Interlocked.Exchange makes it possible to see if you succeeded. On that you can build a locking mechanism.

Comment: I'm a Java person, but looking at the .NET documentation, it looks like "Interlocked.Exchange" is part of the OS kernel (Kernel32.dll), not the .NET runtime. I'd guess that the .NET commands are being compiled down to calls to that kernel instruction.