# python parallel execution of nested loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have below code sample

```
from time import sleep
import asyncio


def background(f):
   def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
      return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None,f,*args,**kwargs)
   return wrapper

@background
def loop_function(i):
    for j in range(10):
        loop_function2(j)

def loop_function2(i):
    for k in range(10):
        sleep(2)
        loop_function3(k)


def loop_function3(i):
    print(i)
    sleep(2)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
looper = asyncio.gather(*[loop_function(i) for i in range(100) ])
loop.run_until_complete(looper)
```

I just tried produce my problem with sample code,

So how can I  make this code parallel for nested as well.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not how asyncio works, at all. Consider googling "asyncio vs. threading" and take your pick.

Comment: Aside: [Don't use the word "parallel"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58990516/9816919) if you're using a single CPU core.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to achieve this by multiprocessing

Comment: Use [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) for the best introductory multiprocessing experience.

Comment: @Gaberocksall, can you help with threading, how can I get them processed